# "editable" prop doesn't work for LexicalComposer

Tags: reactjs, rte, lexicaljs

I'm making a rich text editor with Lexical react. I'm reasonably experienced in React. My problem is I can't get the editor to flip between editable and readonly modes. It's stuck in whatever mode it's set when I first load the app. Here is the code snippet - as you can see, I print out the "editable" value and confirm it changes between `true` and `false` correctly (but the editor mode doesn't change with it):

```
  editorConfig = {
    ...
    editable: editable,
  }
  console.log(`editable is ${editable}`);
  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `useLexicalComposerContext` in some place wrapped by `LexicalComposer` to get `editor` and update its state like this.

```
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";

export default function MyStateChangeButtons() {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => editor.setEditable(true)}>
        make editable true
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => editor.setEditable(false)}>
        make editable false
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how you can call `MyStateChangeButtons` component inside `LexicalComposer`:

```
<LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
  <div className="editor-container">
    <PlainTextPlugin
      contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
      placeholder={<Placeholder />}
    />
    <OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
    <HistoryPlugin />
    <TreeViewPlugin />
    <EmoticonPlugin />
    <MyCustomAutoFocusPlugin />
  </div>
  <MyStateChangeButtons />
</LexicalComposer>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lexical-plain-text-example-forked-gm51j9?file=/src/MyStateChangeButtons.js:108-128) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I sort of had some inkling of the plugin mechanism, but had never written one. I ended up including it in the same file as the composer (like how it's done in this example https://github.com/facebook/lexical/discussions/2583).

Answer (score 0):

```
function TextLoader({ note, editable = false }) {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    // defines whether the editor is on edit or read mode
    editor.setEditable(editable);    if (note) {
      editor.setEditorState(editor.parseEditorState(note.body));
    }
  }, [editor, note, editable]);

  return null;
}

<LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
  <div className="editor-container">
    <div className="editor-inner">
      <RichTextPlugin
        contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
        placeholder={<Placeholder />}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <TextLoader note={note} editable={editable} />
</LexicalComposer>
```